# div#someid vs only #someid?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference in using

```
#mb > a
```

vs

```
div#mb > a
```

in the code below?  It seems to be produce the same result.

```
    <style>
    #mb > a {
    background:#333;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:#999;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    </style>


<div id="mb">
    <a href="#">Link1</a><a href="#">Link2</a><a href="#">Link3</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58mkz/ --without div reference

http://jsfiddle.net/aZrPy/ --with div reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div#mb` is more specific, and targets only the `div` having the id `mb`.
`#mb` is less specific and targets `any` element having the id `mb`.
The first rule is better as you can override weaker rules and it takes greater precedence.

It is producing the same result as there is only one element with id `mb` that too which is a `div`. See the difference here in [One](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/aZrPy/1/) and [Two](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/58mkz/1/) using `nav` elements.

The following two are some code samples, demonstrating what is selected, with each element assumed to be in a separate html file (so no same id conflicts).

#### `div#mb`:

```
<div id="mb"></div> <!--Selected-->

<span id="mb"></span> <!--Not Selected-->

<div id="something"></div> <!--Not Selected-->
```

#### `#mb`:

```
<div id="mb"></div> <!--Selected-->

<span id="mb"></span> <!--Selected-->

<div id="something"></div> <!--Not Selected-->

<p id="something"></p>
```

The same applies to `div#mb > a` and `#mb > a`:

#### `div#mb > a`:

```
<div id="mb">
     <a></a> selected
     <div>
        <a></a> not selected - not direct child
     </div>
</div>

<div id="mbtwo">
     <a></a> not selected
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct, but shouldn't an ID only be used with one and only one element?

Comment: @PatrickAllen Each element for the first two code samples is in a different file. Thanks for notifying, I addded a note in the answer.

Comment: @downvoter.not(Patrick) Please at least leave a comment explaining if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

`div#mb` will only select `#mb` if it is a `div` (eg, if `#mb` was a `span`, it wouldn't select it). Also, it is more specific. Eg, `div#mb` will override `#mb`, if styles have been applied elsewhere. It's unnecessary if `#mb` will only ever exist once as a div, and you aren't overriding any existing styles.

Answer (score 1):

`#mb > a` will target any anchor element whose are direct children of any element with id `mb`.

`div#mb > a` will target any anchor element whose are direct children of any **div** element with id `mb`

However, because `id` must be unique, `#mb` is the same as `div#mb` so there's no difference here.

Answer (score 0):

`div#mb > a` specifies that the id mb must be the id of a div while `#mb > a` specifies that the id mb could belong to any element.

The *more specific* you get, the css rule is stronger and is able to override weaker rules.